# Folium maps not showing up on jupyter notebook uploaded on github

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, folium

I have successfully rendered folium maps on my jupyter notebook by increasing the data limit when launching jupyter from anaconda prompt like this:

```
"jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1.0e10"
```

However, when I have uploaded the notebook to Github, rather than the map I had processed, I got a blank window.

How can I render these maps? Is it possible to increase the data_rate_limit on the notebook when it is being launched through github?

Comment: I just noticed that too.  I hope someone answers this.  You can use nbviewer as a possible workaround http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/

Comment: Alright, I'll check that out. I myself worked around this problem by using my one free page on github to host a html version of my notebook, which could display the maps correctly. But, that can only work once, and I need an actual solution.

Comment: I have tried gmaps, bokeh and folium, none of them renders on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

If there's any Javascript in Folium maps, it will not render on GitHub. For security reasons, GitHub does not execute any javascript while rendering notebooks.

From GitHub [docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github),

> The interactive features of the notebook, such as custom JavaScript
>   plots, will not work in your repository on GitHub